# API Gateway call not enforcing AWS_IAM authentication

Tags: aws-api-gateway

I've set up an API gateway to a lambda function. It's a really simple POST call to a simple function that takes a string in and returns a string.

The call works but when I configured the API call's authorization to require AWS_IAM it just kept allowing calls to succeed - even calls from a simple little test app I wrote that makes no attempt to set authorization parameters. It's the same from Postman - I set it to no authorization and it still works.

I have to be missing something.
Can anyone tell me what, please?

Thanks,

Adam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you remember to redeploy the API to your stage after updating the method to require AWS_IAM authorization?